# "while ( strlen($tmppwd) < 20 )..." returns strings shorter than 20 characters

Tags: php, while-loop, strlen

I am trying to generate a random string in the exact length of 20 characters and getting unexpected behavior from my program,
so curious about what I am missing.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $tmppwd ="";
    while ( strlen($tmppwd) < 20 ) {
      $zufall = rand(33,126);
      if ($zufall != 36 && $zufall !=63 && $zufall !=61) {
        $tmppwd.=chr($zufall);
      }
      echo strlen($tmppwd)." | ";
    }
    exit($tmppwd);
?>
```

This short code-fragment from time to time returns strings that are shorter than 20 characters of length (e.g. "~#z-k") while echo and exit together in that case return-

```
"1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | \~#z-k"...
```

Comment: This works just fine. See https://onecompiler.com/php/3ytggb5qp The random string is of length 20 characters.

Comment: Learn how to test your code. Avoid using `exit` as it exits the entire program execution abruptly.

Comment: I would say, the output is printed inside HTML and so `>` or `"` can cut the output.

Comment: I also wonder, whats's wrong with ? `$ and =` symbols? Why they are forbidden?

Answer (score -2):

here I updated your code now it does not give less than 20 characters of the string
simple add counter when concatenating characters to the string

```
<?php
    $tmppwd ="";
    $countrer = 0;
    while ( $countrer < 20 ) {
      $zufall = rand(33,126);
      if ($zufall != 36 && $zufall !=63 && $zufall !=61) {
        $tmppwd.=chr($zufall);
        $countrer ++;
      }
      echo strlen($tmppwd)." | ";
    }
    exit($tmppwd);
   ?>
```

Comment: OP's code is anyways correct!

Comment: Don't write a solution if you don't understand the problem